# Trouble Deploying App From Tomcat to Sun Java Web Server 7...and I'm a .NET guy :(

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, sun

I am trying to deploy an application that was developed in MyEclipse using Tomcat (originally 5.5 but works with 7) to our demo server (Sun Java Web Server 7). Unfortunately all of the people that had designed the application have left the company. So, here is what I know:

1) The application works as-is in MyEclipse on Tomcat
2) The application was successfully deployed to Sun Java Web Server in the past (presumably with the same build)
3) I can connect to the database from the server with sqldeveloper
4) The application uses: Java EE 5 and Spring framework

**Application settings:**
driver:  **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver**
url **jdbc:oracle:thin@xx.xx.x.xx:service**

Here is the only error I am getting. I get a lot of warnings before and after though:

```
warning:     CORE3283: stderr: com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)

failure:
for host xx.xx.x.xxx trying to GET /application/login.jsp, service-j2ee reports:     com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source. at
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319) at
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557) at
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477) at
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525) at
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128) at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113) at
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:379) at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455) at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463) at
org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:187) at
gov.nyc.oer.dao.SiteConfigDao.getSiteConfig(Unknown Source) at
gov.nyc.oer.manager.SiteConfigManager.getSiteConfig(Unknown Source) at
gov.nyc.oer.manager.SiteConfigManager.afterPropertiesSet(Unknown Source) at
gov.nyc.oer.manager.SiteConfigManager.getValue(Unknown Source) at
org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:67) at
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:80) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:917) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:373) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:457) at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:351) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:917) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:398) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at
org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169) at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183) at
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:255) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:586) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:556) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:586) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:556) at
com.sun.webserver.connector.nsapi.NSAPIProcessor.service(NSAPIProcessor.java:160)
```

**Server Configuration:**
**Java:** Enabled
**Java Home:** ${WS_JDK_HOME}
**Ignore Environment Class Path:** Enabled
**Class Path Prefix:** None
**Server Class Path:**
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/webserv-rt.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/pwc.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/ant.jar
${java.home}/lib/tools.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/ktsearch.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/webserv-jstl.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/jsf-impl.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/jsf-api.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/webserv-jwsdp.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/container-auth.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/mail.jar
${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/activation.jar
**Class Path Suffix:** ${WS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/ojdbc14.jar
**JVM Options:**
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=login.conf
-Xms128m -Xmx256m
-Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Just a long shot: You're defining a system property named "jdbc.drivers".  Does your application expect a property named "jdbc.driver" (without the "s")?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your database connection is not defined on your sun java web server 7. On [this website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0793/gczmw/index.html) you can find out how to define it.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance in this area; but I thought that if I define the connection information in the code (driver, username, password) and provide the ojdbc14.jar (see the class path suffix), I shouldn't have to set up a resource right? Under the JVM Options configuration I configured the oracle driver.

Comment: You describe setting up a connection, but the exception is from a connection pool.  you must configure the connection pool in your sun blah server.  Try a Google search for "c3p0 connection pool".